# Keep rows data with specific string value in R

Tags: r, regex, string-comparison

First, I have list of strings:

```
/index.php/abc/def
/link/view/id/123
/subject/view/id/456
```

And then, I have datasets like this:

```
Date and Time          Request
2016-01-17 05:46:26    aladdine.com/view/id/786
2016-01-17 05:46:30    aladdine.com/subject/view/id/456
2016-01-17 05:46:31    aladdine.com/pub/link/view/id/123
2016-01-17 05:46:44    aladdine.com/index.php/abc/def/ghi
2016-01-17 05:46:58    aladdine.com/brs/view/id.266
```

How can I keep the datasets that have similar text to the previous list?

Output:

```
Date and Time          Request
2016-01-17 05:46:30    aladdine.com/subject/view/id/456
2016-01-17 05:46:31    aladdine.com/pub/link/view/id/123
2016-01-17 05:46:44    aladdine.com/index.php/abc/def/ghi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same dataset @Cinnamon Star used, you could do:

```
dataSet <- CO2;
iList <- list("Qn1", "Mn1", "Mc1");
```

Join all the strings into a single regular expression pattern of the type `(str1|str2|str3)`:

```
pat = paste(unlist (iList),collapse = "|")
pat = paste0("(",pat,")")
```

Then do a grepl to determine which lines contain that text in column `Plant`.

```
dataSet[grepl(pattern = pat,x = dataSet$Plant),]
```

Result:

```
   Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake
1    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0
2    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4
3    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  250   34.8
4    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  350   37.2
5    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  500   35.3
6    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled  675   39.2
7    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled 1000   39.7
43   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled   95   10.6
44   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled  175   19.2
45   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled  250   26.2
46   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled  350   30.0
47   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled  500   30.9
48   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled  675   32.4
49   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled 1000   35.5
64   Mc1 Mississippi    chilled   95   10.5
65   Mc1 Mississippi    chilled  175   14.9
66   Mc1 Mississippi    chilled  250   18.1
67   Mc1 Mississippi    chilled  350   18.9
68   Mc1 Mississippi    chilled  500   19.5
69   Mc1 Mississippi    chilled  675   22.2
70   Mc1 Mississippi    chilled 1000   21.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the `CO2` example out of the R database. Please assign your dataset to `dataSet`, your list to `iList` and please change all occurrences of `dataSet$Plant` to the column you are interested in (probably `dataSet$Request`).

The resulting dataset is saved in `results`.

```
rm(list = ls());

dataSet <- CO2;

varsToCheck <- dataSet$Plant;

iList <- list("Qn1", "Mn1", "Mc1");

# Iterate over all rows
for(i in 1:length(dataSet$Plant)) {
  # Extract string for checking
  validateString <- varsToCheck[i];
  # Iterate over all match criterions
  for(j in 1:length(iList)) {
    # Extract the match criterion
    matchString <- iList[[j]];
    # Validate if part of the string match the criterion
    if(grepl(matchString, validateString)) {
      # Create results object when we first add a row
      if(exists("results")) {
        results <- rbind(results, dataSet[i,]);
      } else {
        results <- dataSet[i,];
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, that's  so helpful .. but i have the problem with the results. why the results just show the last row of dataset which match with the iList? So that, results will always have 1 row

Comment: I have no idea, maybe I miss something, but for me it works fine. Take the example and try it yourself.